# Project doesn't launch when I use 'ext.js' but works when I use 'extjs-all.js'

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I used these 2 commands to compress my project;

```
sencha create jsb -a http://localhost/Project/app.html -p a.jsb3 -v
sencha build -p a.jsb3 -v -d .
```

and then used the following code in the app.html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app-all.js"></script>
```

But, the problem is that when I run the application, I get an error saying

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/Project/MyApp/view/PersonView.js?_dc=1347769776730"
```

and many other views; but when I change `ext.js` to `ext-all.js` everything works.

But if I use ext-all.js I think I am calling all the extjs classes, and this could reduce the start up speed. How should I correct my code?

Comment: What does that do and where should i add it ?

Comment: Disregard my comment. That won't help in your situation.

Comment: Any other idea as what's going on with my code ?

Comment: Try to include generated **all-classes.js** script instead of ext.js and app-all.js

Answer (score 1):

You should include ext.js or ext-dev.js in app.html when you call `sencha build tools` (not ext-all variants). Remember to enable dynamic loader as well configured to look in src folder for ExtJS classes. Then a JSB3 file with correct ExtJS references will be created.

```
 Ext.Loader.setConfig({
            enabled: true,
            paths: {
                'Ext': '/ext-4.1.1/src', 
                'Ext.ux': ... // Set UX path if you use any ux classes 
                // Set path for your classes as well
            }
        });
```

Run the website with Firebug enabled and fix any warnings in console tab.